# nvidia GPU suddently not used anymore at all

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hardware-acceleration

Somehow my NVIDIA GPU is not being used at all anymore (just for displaying the screen).

Take a look at this picture:
[image]

There are a lot of options missing.

Also, take a look at this:
[image]

Usually 600MBit of the GPU's vram should be used which is not the case and there's no process listed.

Usually there shoule be xorg and firefox listed.

All gnome animations are broken, browser animations won't work as expected either.
In gnome, there's no animation anymore. It just happens immediately.

I have no clue where I could find more information and I think I already had the same problem but under Arch (Manjaro). There I had to completely remove the drivers and use the nvidia's installer which was really annoying because cuda was installed from the repository and whenever that updated I had to manually update the nvidia driver.

Somehow this is saying that the driver was installed manually which is not the case:
[image]

My Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS

I manually installed nvidia-tools because they were not available.
Maybe this is relevant:
[image]

And I just did this, I'm going to reboot.

```
    ~  sudo ubuntu-drivers install                               ✔  7s  
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515
  libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-515
  libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515
  libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515 nvidia-compute-utils-515
  nvidia-kernel-source-515 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515
  libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-515
  libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515
  libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515 nvidia-compute-utils-515
  nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
0 aktualisiert, 15 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen 280 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 666 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Holen:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-cfg1-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [94.0 kB]
Holen:2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-compute-515 i386 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [54.2 MB]
Holen:3 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-decode-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1’449 kB]
Holen:4 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-decode-515 i386 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1’669 kB]
Holen:5 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 amd64 1:1.1.9-1.1 [26.1 kB]
Holen:6 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-encode-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [45.3 kB]
Holen:7 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-encode-515 i386 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [49.1 kB]
Holen:8 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-extra-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [60.9 kB]
Holen:9 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-fbc1-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [50.6 kB]
Holen:10 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted i386 libnvidia-fbc1-515 i386 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [55.7 kB]
Holen:11 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 libnvidia-gl-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [189 MB]
Holen:12 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [114 kB]
Holen:13 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [31.3 MB]
Holen:14 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1’483 kB]
Holen:15 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-515 amd64 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [467 kB]
Es wurden 280 MB in 18 s geholt (15.7 MB/s).                                   
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 wird gewählt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 221378 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../00-libnvidia-cfg1-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-compute-515:i386 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../01-libnvidia-compute-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../02-libnvidia-decode-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-decode-515:i386 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../03-libnvidia-decode-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../04-libnvidia-egl-wayland1_1%3a1.1.9-1.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64 (1:1.1.9-1.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../05-libnvidia-encode-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-encode-515:i386 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../06-libnvidia-encode-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../07-libnvidia-extra-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../08-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../09-libnvidia-fbc1-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb ...
Entpacken von libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../10-libnvidia-gl-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: Kein Paket gefunden, das auf libnvidia-gl-510 passt
Entpacken von libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket nvidia-compute-utils-515 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../11-nvidia-compute-utils-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket nvidia-kernel-source-515 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../12-nvidia-kernel-source-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../13-xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket nvidia-driver-515 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../14-nvidia-driver-515_515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von nvidia-driver-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-extra-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-kernel-source-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64 (1:1.1.9-1.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-decode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-gl-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-compute-utils-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
Achtung: auf den von Ihnen angegebene persönlichen Ordner »/nonexistent« kann nicht zugegriffen werden: No such file or directory
Systembenutzer »nvidia-persistenced« (UID 128) wird hinzugefügt …
Neue Gruppe »nvidia-persistenced« (GID 136) wird hinzugefügt …
Neuer Benutzer »nvidia-persistenced« (UID 128) wird mit Gruppe »nvidia-persistenced« hinzugefügt …
Persönlicher Ordner »/nonexistent« wird nicht erstellt.
libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-encode-515:amd64 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-driver-515 (515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für man-db (2.10.2-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) werden verarbeitet ...
    ~                                                           ✔  31s 
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by first running "`sudo ubuntu-drivers install`" and then rebooting once.

Looks like Ubuntu messed with the drivers.

Comment: It's `autoinstall` and no, Ubuntu didn't messed with the drivers. Users do that on their own.

Comment: I didn't do anything, It must've been Ubuntu - @ChanganAuto. The only thing I did was installing nvidia-settings and nvidia-utils.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  autoinstall is deprecated, "use install instead"